# How do I display dynamic text at the mouse cursor via C++/MFC in a Win32 application

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I would like to be able to display some dynamic text at the mouse 
cursor location in a win32 app, for instance to give an X,Y coordinate that 
would move with the cursor as though attached. I can do this during a 
mousemove event using a TextOut() call for the window at the mouse 
coordinates and invalidate a rectange around a stored last cursor position 
to clear up the previous output. However this can suffer from flickering and 
cause problems with other things being drawn in a window such as tracker 
boxes. Is there a better way to do this, perhaps using the existing cursor 
drawing/invalidating mechanism ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider a small transparent window that you move to follow the mouse. In particular, since Windows 2000, [Layered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599(VS.85).aspx#layered) windows seem to be the weapon of choice (confession: no personal experience there).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via ToolTips - check out [CToolTipCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b4cb3a5(VS.80).aspx).

If you want flicker free tracking ToolTips then you will need to derive your own classes from CToolTipCtrl that use the [trackActivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760421(VS.85).aspx) messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite OnSetCursor to get a dynamic mouse cursor. I just found a German tutorial.

[German tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20050320074845/http://www.cpp-tutor.de/mfc/mfc/kap7/tut/tut4.htm)

[English translated tutorial](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=de&sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.archive.org%2Fweb%2F20050320074845%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.cpp-tutor.de%2Fmfc%2Fmfc%2Fkap7%2Ftut%2Ftut4.htm&sandbox=1)